# Comparing routes using code?

Tags: software-recommendations, routing, comparison

I am looking for a way to compare routes of two or more persons to be taken by car.

```
Person 1 has a starting point A1 and a destination point A2.
Person 2 has a starting point B1 and a destination point B2.
[...]
```

What I would like to accomplish:

1. Check, if A1 and B1 are close to each other.
2. Calculate walking and/or driving distance from A1 to B1.
3. Save the individual routes of Person 1 and Person 2 in a way, that allows for performant comparison to other routes / route points.
4. Identify, if the routes to be taken of Person 1 and Person 2 are similar enough, to have at least same route parts.

Are there already (open source) examples of code around that I haven't found yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize GraphHopper for this task.

> Check, if A1 and B1 are close to each other.

use the DistanceCalc to calculate this

> Calculate walking and/or driving distance from A1 to B1.

use GraphHopper.route for this

> Save the individual routes of Person 1 and Person 2 in a way, that allows for performant comparison to other routes / route points.
>   Identify, if the routes to be taken of Person 1 and Person 2 are similar enough, to have at least same route parts.

Use response.calcEdges for this, which is the list of junctions as integer values and should be easy to do comparison etc